# configure clickstart to deploy automatically play2 application

Tags: jenkins, playframework, playframework-2.2, cloudbees

We have Play 2 application we want to build and deploy automatically via cloudbees. We figured out a way to do it, we just missing the right settings to configure it by default.

We have to set "containerType=play2". In the Jenkins UI of cloudbees, we managed to deploy the application through setting

Post-build Actions>Deploy Applications>CloudBees RUN@cloud service>Applications>Runtime parameters

name: containerType
value: play2

[clickstart.json](https://github.com/commercetools/sphere-fedora/blob/master/deploy/cloudbees/clickstart.json), [config.xml](https://github.com/commercetools/sphere-fedora/blob/master/deploy/cloudbees/config.xml)